# DELETE method with request body in axios and laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, axios, laravel-5.8

I try to delete backup with DELETE method in Laravel and Axios but the request is comming back empty.

**Controller**

```
     /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     * @param Request $request
     */
    public function destroy(Request $request)
    {
        return $request->all();
    }
```

**Route**

```
Route::middleware(['auth'])->prefix('backup')->group(function() {
    Route::get('/', 'BackupController@index');
    Route::delete('/delete', 'BackupController@destroy')->name('backup.delete');
});
```

**Axios Request**

```
axios.delete(`/backup/delete`,{data: {filename: filename}} )
.then((response)=>{
      console.log(response.data)
   })
.catch((err) => console.error(err.response.data.errors));
```

**Console.log(response)**
[image]

What is the problem with my code?

Comment: You're returning the request. That doesn't look like a valid thing to return as a response. Maybe try returning some text to make sure that works first

Comment: I used the text, it returns correctly, but the body sent by the DELETE method returns empty.

Comment: whats in ` console.log(response)` ?

Comment: I added `console.log(response)` to my question @EmekaMbah

Comment: what happens when you try to access this in your browser `/backup/delete`

Comment: When I try to access to it in my browser error raised because Laravel does not allow access to this method by URL : `The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: DELETE.` @EmekaMbah

Comment: That's correct, just wanted to be sure the URL works

Comment: Have you tested Axios with a spoof parameter, just to be sure?

`axios.delete(`/backup/delete`,{data: {filename: filename, _method: 'DELETE'}} )`

Answer (score 1):

You send over axios the the filename. Then you have fetch in the destroy method the filename and get the model from the database.

**Route**

```
Route::delete('api/delete/{filename}', BackupController@destroy')->name('backup.delete');
```

**Controller**

```
$model = App\Models\Backup::where('filename', $request->filename)::first();
$model->destroy();
```

### Update

Sending the parameters via the body using the DELETE method is not recommended. Some servers do not support it. However.

1. Change the method from delete to put or POST

```
axios.put(`/backup/delete`,{data: {filename: filename}} )
.then((response)=>{
      console.log(response.data)
   })
.catch((err) => console.error(err.response.data.errors));
```

2. Adjust your Route

```php
Route::delete('/delete', 'BackupController@destroy')->name('backup.delete');
```

Then you can fetch in your Controller over the Request Object the parameter (filename).

Comment: I need to send filename as body in DELETE request not in url